# How to add iptable support to the kernel (for Wheezy/Sid release)

Tags: linux, iptables, kernel

I am running an ARM processor (similar to the raspberry pi) and my kernel doesnt natively support iptables. If I run apt-get install iptables, it successfully installs but NAT tables are unable to be created and the more advanced stuff cannot be used. When I try add a NAT table, it specifically mentions that I might not have support for iptables in my kernel.

My question: How do I **just** add the iptables support to my kernel?

My details:

Welcome to Linaro 12.11 (GNU/Linux 3.4.29+ armv7l)
Wheezy/Sid (cat /etc/debian_version)
Already installed the iptables package (apt-get install iptables), just need kernel support.

Thanks a mil!

Jared

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the relevant kernel modules:

```
modprobe iptable_nat iptable_filter
```

Comment: Is that all I need to do? I already have loaded the iptables by using a custom kernel (wasn't ideal, lots of things are not working as they should). Thanks

Comment: If you have iptables compiled in as a module in your custom kernel, and then load the iptable modules, then yes. that's all you need to do to "just add iptables support".